# How to overlay 2 layouts in Kivy (Python)?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, overlay

I am trying to make an app with a background grid and a top layer of interactive elements, I am having trouble overlaying the second layer via python, so like the title says is there a way to overlay 2 or more layouts in Kivy in ?

Here's what I am looking for

[image: overlay 2 layouts kivy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

Set the `opacity` of the first layer / layout to 0.5

[Widget class » opacity](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.opacity)

> opacity
>
> Opacity of the widget and all its children.
>
> The opacity attribute controls the opacity of the widget and its
>   children. Be careful, it’s a cumulative attribute: the value is
>   multiplied by the current global opacity and the result is applied to
>   the current context color.
>
> ...
>
> opacity is a [NumericProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.NumericProperty) and defaults to 1.0.

[Kivy Graphics Line » points](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line.points)

> *points:* list
>
> List of points in the format (x1, y1, x2, y2…)
>
> Property for getting/settings points of the line
>
> **Warning**
>
> This will always reconstruct the whole graphics from the new points
>   list. It can be very CPU expensive.

[Kivy Graphics Line » circle](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line.circle)

> circle
>
> Use this property to build a circle, without calculating the points.
>   You can only set this property, not get it.
>
> The argument must be a tuple of (center_x, center_y, radius,
>   angle_start, angle_end, segments):
>
> - center_x and center_y represent the center of the circle
> - radius represent the radius of the circle
> - (optional) angle_start and angle_end are in degree. The default value is 0 and 360.
> - (optional) segments is the precision of the ellipse. The default value is calculated from the range between angle.
>
> Note that it’s up to you to close the circle or not.

## Example

### main.py - without kv

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.metrics import dp

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class Overlay2Layouts(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Overlay2Layouts, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = Window.size

        layout1 = BoxLayout(opacity=0.5)
        with layout1.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)   # red colour
            Line(points=[self.center_x, self.height / 4, self.center_x, self.height * 3/4], width=dp(2))
            Line(points=[self.width * 3/ 4, self.center_y, self.width /4, self.center_y], width=dp(2))

        layout2 = BoxLayout()
        with layout2.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 1)   # black colour
            Line(circle=[self.center_x, self.center_y, 190], width=dp(2))

        self.add_widget(layout1)
        self.add_widget(layout2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runTouchApp(Overlay2Layouts())
```

### main.py - using kv and Python

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        opacity: 0.5
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Line:
                width: dp(2.)
                points: [self.center_x, self.height / 4, self.center_x, self.height * 3/4]
            Line:
                width: dp(2.)
                points: [root.width * 3/ 4, self.center_y, root.width /4, self.center_y]
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Line:
                width: dp(2.)
                circle: (root.center_x, root.center_y, 190)

'''))
```

## Output

[image: Overlay 2 layouts]

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for an equivalent in python which I should have mentioned before (edited the question) I am trying to translate your example right now.

Comment: can't figure out this bit in python :```points: [root.width``` any idea ?

Comment: *points* is a list and part of class Kivy graphics Line. The points are in the format (x1, y1, x2, y2…). In the example, `root.width` is referring to the Screen's width.

Comment: I get that, but if you were recreating the.kv file in python  you would need to reference root somehow, so far I haven't find the correct way of binding it.

Comment: Implement a `class Overlay2Layouts(Screen):` and this is will be the root. Reference it using `self`. Please refer to updated post for example without using kv.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer in python, the overlays didn't resize when the window changed size, so this is my solution:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Ellipse, Rectangle
from kivy.metrics import dp


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.draw)
        self.bind(size=self.draw)
        self.layout1 = BoxLayout(opacity=0.3)
        self.layout2 = BoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.layout1)
        self.add_widget(self.layout2)

    def draw(self, *args):
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(1,1,.5,1)
            self.bg = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.layout1.canvas.clear()
        with self.layout1.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)   # red colour
            Line(points=[self.center_x, self.height / 4, self.center_x, self.height * 3/4], width=dp(2))
            Line(points=[self.width * 3/ 4, self.center_y, self.width /4, self.center_y], width=dp(2))
        self.layout2.canvas.clear()
        with self.layout2.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 1)   # black colour
            Line(circle=[self.center_x, self.center_y, 190], width=dp(2))


class Overlays_3(App):
    title = "Overlays_3"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Overlays_3().run()
```